# Get the Latest Date In another SharePoint page with Ajax

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I'm getting an Error 404: Page Cannot Be Found

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = getUserInfo();

    function getUserInfo(){

        var siteurls = '/sites/Workflow/SRF1';
        console.log(siteurls);

        $.ajax({
            url: siteurls + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('AllItems')/items?/Title,Date",
            method: "GET",
            headers: { "Accept": "application/json; odata=verbose" },
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.d.results.length > 0 ) {
                    console.log(value.Date.title);
                    $.each(data.d.results, function(key,value){
                        $("input[title='Currentdate']").val(value.Date);
                    });     
                }  
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert("Error: "+ data);
            }
        }); //End AJAX      
    }//End Function
</script>
```

I think I might have an error in the Ajax URL

Comment: Modify it to use `..../getbytitle('AllItems')/items?select=Title,Date"`, also, use the absolute url like `https://site-url/subsite/.../getbytitle('AllItems')/items?select=Title,Date"`

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: with this reference "/sites/Workflow/SRF1/Lists/getbytitle('AllItems')/items?select=Title,Date:1"